# What's the name of this game in the photo?

Tags: game-identification

This image is from a website that allows you play classic games in a browser. It appears on a video on home page. They didn't put the name of the game there.

[image]

Which game is this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That would be [Dreamweb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DreamWeb). That gent on the left is a near-constant element of the HUD in that game.

Answer (score 3):

### Dreamweb

**Release year:** 1994

**Platform:** DOS

**Age rating:**: 18 years

**Game cover:**

[image: DreamWeb Cover]

**Game license:** Freeware

**Story:** There is a disturbance in the Dreamweb, a barrier between this world and the next. Seven evil leaders are threatening to destroy it, meaning the certain end of everything. You control Ryan in this top-down adventure game that features heavy pixel hunting and hard puzzles.

Furthermore, the game is now freeware and available on many sites, like [ScummVM](https://www.scummvm.org/games/#games-dreamweb) for instance.

### Example Screenshots [image]

[image]

**Review**: If you'd like to read a review, I wrote one many years ago. [You can read the review at The Retro Spirit here](https://retro.gg/game/dreamweb/16#review)
*(note: written by the undersigned, it's in Norwegian but you can Google Translate)*